# Pulling in Column Count in Custom Gallery

Tags: gallery

So close, but I know nothing of php. Would like to be able to pull in columns from wordpress gallery. The very nature of removing the default gallery might make this impossible. I think the secret lies in %s, maybe I can attach column count with another one of these %d inside sprintf(. No Idea what am doing, obviously :)

```
function modified_gallery_shortcode( $attr ) {


$attr['link']   = "file";
$attr['itemtag']  = "";
$attr['icontag']  = "";
$attr['captiontag'] = "p";
$output = gallery_shortcode( $attr );
$output = strip_tags( $output, '<a><img><li><p>' );
$from = array(  
        "class='gallery-item'", 
        "class='gallery-icon landscape'", 
        "a href=",
     //  "class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'"
    );      
$to = array( 
      "",
      "",
      "a itemprop=\"contentUrl\" rel=\"group\" href=",
      "",
);
$output = str_replace( $from, $to, $output);
$output = sprintf( '<div class="gallery gallery-columns-{$columns} " itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">%s</div>', $output );

 return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sprintf is a way to use variables within a string easily. `%d` designates a digit and `%s` is any string.

So think of it like this

`sprintf( '<div class="%s">%s</div>', $var1, $var2 );`

So for your example, you'd need something like:

```
$output = sprintf( '<div class="gallery gallery-columns-%s" itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">%s</div>', $columns, $output );
```

The only thing from your code I'm not seeing is where `$columns` gets defined.

Comment: My code spits out 2 event though I change columns in admin `extract(shortcode_atts(array(  'columns'    => 3, ), $attr, 'gallery'));$columns = intval($columns);`

Comment: thanks it was simply`extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'columns'    => 3,
  ), $attr));`